# Структура таблицы характеристики для товара Laravel

Tags: sql, база-данных, laravel

Всем привет. Делаю учебный инет магазин на Laravel и наткнулся на сложность. Т.к. опыт не большой в структурах БД, то найти решение самостоятельно не смог.
Сайт о бытовой технике. Как должна будет выглядеть таблица характеристики, ведь например у холодильника и блендера абсолютно разные характеристики, что есть у одного, нет у другого.
Сори, если банальный вопрос.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую рассмотреть вариант хранения характеристик в формате json в одной из ячеек таблицы товаров. В sql есть отдельный тип данных json. В laravel его легко преобразовать в массив.

Это сильно упростит вам работу.

А если как вы хотите, то для того чтобы хранить характеристики вам нужно 3 таблицы: таблица товаров, таблица наименований характеристик и таблица значений характеристик

```
products
id name  

features
id name

feature_product
id product_id feature_id value
```

Comment: Да, погуглил, с JSON на самом деле куда проще. А что Вы думаете на счет хранения изображение товара, их так же может быть неограниченное количество. Ранее мне советовали создать отдельную таблицу для них или через foreign key связать с таблицей продукты. Хорошее решение или воспользоваться JSON тут так же будет лучше(один комментатор сказал, там где обсуждались изображения, что JSON будет своеобразным костылем)?

Comment: Изображения также можно хранить в json формате, точнее путь к картинкам. При этом формат приблизительно такой {'full':'images/img1200x980.jpg','thumb':'images/img300x200'}. Далее можно преобразовать свойство в объект типа $product->images = json_decode($product->images, false); и дальше использовать как $product->images->full;